# Handling 100 continue on the server side with asp.net core

Tags: c#, http, .net-core

I'm trying to override the default behavior of the framework to **always** return 100 continue after a request with expect:100-continue is sent. No matter what I tried I still see the server always responds with 100 continue. The only documentation I found explain how to disable the 100 continue header from the client side (via ServicePointManager).

The reason I'm trying to do so is to validate the headers first and than return 417 or some other final status in reply to a post request.

the RFC states:

> Requirements for HTTP/1.1 origin servers:
>
> ```
>   - Upon receiving a request which includes an Expect request-header
>     field with the "100-continue" expectation, an origin server MUST
>     either respond with 100 (Continue) status and continue to read
>     from the input stream, or respond with a final status code. The
>     origin server MUST NOT wait for the request body before sending
>     the 100 (Continue) response. If it responds with a final status
>     code, it MAY close the transport connection or it MAY continue
>     to read and discard the rest of the request.  It MUST NOT
>     perform the requested method if it returns a final status code.
> ```

results from curl:

[image]

Comment: wow, 2 years without an answer or comment. Missing part in asp.net core I think

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?  Same Issue.

Comment: No AliK, but it was 4 years ago, maybe something have changed.